# Create a select in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I created a select using react js.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const options = [
  {
    id: "test1",
    label: "label1"
  },
  {
    id: "test1",
    label: "label2"
  },
  {
    id: "color",
    label: "Test"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        {options.map((i) => {
          return <option value={i.id}>{i.label}</option>;
        })}
      </select>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a situation where the value (ID) is the same but the title is different like in the case with 2 first options.

Trying to click on `label2` the selected arrow still selected on the previous (label1). How to fix this? 
 demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/red-microservice-tesgs?file=/src/App.js:0-669

Comment: One option would be to give each option an actual unique ID (as well as the current ID, which I would rename to "value") and store that. Then you can use it to set the correct row to selected, and to access the relevant objects value when required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can not change the ids (the best way is to have unique ids), you can rely on the index of your options array:

```
const options = [
  {
    id: "test1",
    label: "label1"
  },
  {
    id: "test1",
    label: "label2"
  },
  {
    id: "color",
    label: "Test"
  }
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    id: "",
    index: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (e, index) => {
    setValue({ id: e.target.value, index: index });
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <select
        value={options[value.index]}
        onChange={(e, index) => handleChange(e, index)}
      >
        {options.map((i, index) => {
          return (
            <option key={index} value={i.id}>
              {i.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to provide a `selected` attribute to your `<option />` element, e.g:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

/*[...]*/

<select onChange={handleChange}>
  {options.map(({id, label}, index) => {
    return <option key={index} value={id} selected={value === id}>{label}</option>;
  })}
</select>
```

Also, note the `key` prop above, you should *always* have this when iterating over JSX nodes. This should be a unique value to that index, I've used the array index, but this should really be something like the ID. If you use the index, you'll introduce all sorts of odd bugs when the source data changes.

As for the duplicate `id` in your array, as mentioned above, this seems like a poor data structure to me, personally. I'd ensure your `id` is always unique.

What purpose do you have for it to be duplicate, out of interest?